# oracle connection string or host name , port number and TNS

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

i install Oracle on my machine from  [ORACLE website](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/xe-downloads.html)

after installation i am able to log in using below command "sqlplus / as sysdba"

[image]

a able able to log in using "sqlplus system/"Password" as well

**question :**
i want to connect database using third party tool like SQL developer , how i will get TNS or Host name and port number  ?

Comment: did you search tnsnames.ora file? it is your local machine, and if you run your client app on the same machine why dont you use localhost as host name

Comment: I think the default database is defined by environment variable `ORACLE_SID` Run `tnsping` on this DB to get all information about port and host. (which should be 1521 and `localhost`)

Comment: Host name is `localhost` or your computer's public IP address or host name (this has nothing to do with Oracle itself). Default port is 1521 and can be omitted. Instance name is `xe`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic problem one runs when the database is started but listener service isn't. Nothing to worry, below command can help you to check if your listener is active.

`lsnrctl status`

If this says, listener is not listening add below 2 .ora files and restart Listener.

```
$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/listener.ora
$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
```

> Listener Commands

```
    lsnrctl start
    lsnrctl stop
    lsnrctl status
```

Also pasting sample .ora files to make your job easier.

> listener.ora

```
LISTENER =
  (ADDRESS_LIST=
       (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))
       (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=PNPKEY)))

SID_LIST_LISTENER=
  (SID_LIST=
      (SID_DESC=
         (GLOBAL_DBNAME=dev)
         (SID_NAME=dev)
         (ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0.1/db_1)
                      #PRESPAWN CONFIG
        (PRESPAWN_MAX=20)
        (PRESPAWN_LIST=
          (PRESPAWN_DESC=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(POOL_SIZE=2)(TIMEOUT=1))
        )
       )
      )
```

> tnsnames.ora

```
dev=
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = dev)
    )
  )
```

> Please ensure you make appropriate changes to `GLOBAL_DBNAME`, `SID_NAME`, `ORACLE_HOME` & `SERVICE_NAME` in both of the above files. Also if you wish to make this database available over your network, get the `HOST` parameter configured as your machine IP instead of `localhost`.